# Where is the preferred place for select list options

Tags: grails, controller, gsp

Writing a grails app and I'm not sure if I should do the "FROM" list in the g:select, or pass it in from a list in the controller.

I know when rendering a list of objects, you have to pass it in through the controller, but what about a simple list?  Should I still pass it from the controller or generate it on the GSP?

Comment: some code samples would definitely be not harmful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on your requirement. Passing the list from the controller and making use of `optionKey` and `optionValue` gives more control over the `<select >` tag.

[Refer docs for more info](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html).

`Should I still pass it from the controller or generate it on the GSP?`

I think let MVC do its work and follow best practice by generating list in controller and simply pass it to view to render instead of generating list in views.